# Dynamic Array Problem (Hacker rank)

Tags: performance, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, swift

I am trying to solve the [Dynamic Array](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem) problem on HackerRank:

> - Create a list, seqList, of N empty sequences, where each sequence is indexed from 0 to N-1. The elements within each of the N sequences also use 0-indexing.
> - Create an integer, lastAnswer, and initialize it to 0.
> - The 2 types of queries that can be performed on your list of sequences (seqList) are described below:
>
>   1. Query: 1 x y
>
>      1. Find the sequence, seq, at index ((x ^ lastAnswer) % N) in seqList.
>      2. Append integer y to sequence seq.
>   2. Query: 2 x y
>
>      1. Find the sequence, seq, at index ((x ^ lastAnswer) % N) in seqList.
>      2. Find the value of element y % size in seq (where size is the size of seq) and assign it to lastAnswer.
>      3. Print the new value of lastAnswer on a new line.

However, I am getting a “time out error” for very large inputs.

Below is my code in Swift so far:

```
func dynamicArray(n: Int, queries: [[Int]]) -> [Int] {
    var sequences: [Int: [Int]] = [:]
    var lastAnswer = 0
    var answerlist = [Int]()
    for query in queries {
        let queryType = query[0]
        let x = query[1]
        let y = query[2]
        switch queryType {
        case 1:
            let seq = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n
            if var sequence = sequences[seq] {
                sequence.append(y)
                sequences[seq] = sequence
            } else {
                sequences[seq] = [y]
            }
        case 2:
            let seq = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n
            let index = y % (sequences[seq])!.count
            lastAnswer = sequences[seq]![index]
            answerlist.append(lastAnswer)
        default: break
        }
    }
    return answerlist
}
```

Can it be further optimised?

Comment: For which input this code is being failed?

Comment: (PFB made me think you Canadian.)

Comment: Please block-quote the gist of the problem statement near the top of your question. Please describe how the code solves the problem - in the code, preferably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose to represent the “list of sequences” as a dictionary

> ```
> var sequences: [Int: [Int]] = [:]
> ```

and here you test if a sequence for the given index already exists, and then either append a new element or create the initial sequence for that index:

> ```
> if var sequence = sequences[seq] {
>     sequence.append(y)
>     sequences[seq] = sequence
> } else {
>     sequences[seq] = [y]
> }
> ```

That can be greatly simplified by using a subscript with a default value:

```
sequences[seq, default: []].append(y)
```

But actually, instead of representing the “list of sequences” as a dictionary I would represent it as an array (of arrays) instead:

```
var sequences: [[Int]] = Array(repeating: [], count: n)
```

The number of sequences is a-priori known, so that there is no advantage of using a dictionary. Appending a new element to a sequences (query type 1) then becomes

```
sequences[seq].append(y)
```

and for query type 2 we get

```
lastAnswer = sequences[seq][index]
answerlist.append(lastAnswer)
```

without the need of forced-unwrapping for the dictionary subscripting.

This should also be more efficient, because (array) index lookups are faster than dictionary lookups.

Some more remarks:

- The type of a variable should not be part of the variable name, e.g. `answers` instead of `answerList`.
- Multiple (related) assignments can be combined to a tuple assignment, e.g.

  ```
  let (queryType, x, y) = (query[0], query[1], query[2])
  ```
- We know that the query type can only be 1 or 2, but a `fatalError()` in the default case helps to find programming errors.

Putting it together, the function could look like this:

```
func dynamicArray(n: Int, queries: [[Int]]) -> [Int] {
    var sequences: [[Int]] = Array(repeating: [], count: n)
    var lastAnswer = 0
    var answers = [Int]()
    for query in queries {
        let (queryType, x, y) = (query[0], query[1], query[2])
        switch queryType {
        case 1:
            let seq = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n
            sequences[seq].append(y)
        case 2:
            let seq = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n
            let index = y % sequences[seq].count
            lastAnswer = sequences[seq][index]
            answers.append(lastAnswer)
        default:
            fatalError("Bad query type")
        }
    }
    return answers
}
```

---

In addition, it seems that most of the time is spent while *reading the input data* into the `queries` array, done by the (HackerRank supplied template) code

> ```
> guard let queriesRowTemp = readLine()?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+$", with: "", options: .regularExpression) else { fatalError("Bad input") }
>
> let queriesRow: [Int] = queriesRowTemp.split(separator: " ").map {
>     if let queriesItem = Int($0) {
>         return queriesItem
>     } else { fatalError("Bad input") }
> }
> ```

Instead of removing trailing whitespace with a regular expression search we can split the input row and ignore empty components:

```
guard let queriesRowTemp = readLine() else { fatalError("Bad input") }
let queriesRow: [Int] = queriesRowTemp.split(separator: " ",
                                             omittingEmptySubsequences: true).map {
    if let queriesItem = Int($0) {
        return queriesItem
    } else { fatalError("Bad input") }
}
```

In my test that cut the time to read 100000 queries down from 3.7 to 1.7 seconds.

Comment: I tried your code. However, the 6 out of 10 test cases are still failing. Your code seems to increase the readability but over all time complexity remained the same. So, the issue i faced is still persisting. Note: I also used 2-D array in my first attempt, but it couldn't help; then after i made sequences as dictionary as it as O(1) complexity in most of the cases. Please refer [link] (https://www.raywenderlich.com/1172-collection-data-structures-in-swift)

Comment: @SiddharthKumar: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Martin. The issue was with the hacker rank template code itself. Great work for pointing it out.